# TYPO3 frontend redirects to Install Tool 8.7.24

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have recently set up a backup of a live website on a local WAMP install.

The TYPO3 backend is working, but whenever I try and load a local version of the site from the frontend the website redirects to the install tool.

Are there any switches or keys in the code that forces a redirect to the install tool, that i might have missed?

Comment: A redirect to the install tool is normally done when the installation is not yet completed. Are you redirected to one of the installations steps or simply in the installtool?

Comment: do you have some configuration, that is domain specific which still point to the original website? e.g. DB-config (Host,port, user, passwort)